# Setting the parameters of PID for 10 °C set point

Tags: temperature, pid-controller, peltier, thermocouple, controller

I have a PID controller (REX C100), connected to a TEC1-12706 (Thermal Electric Cooling) and a thermocouple K-type. I want to set 10 °C on my PID.

The problem is that the actual temperature in PID is not stable. It fluctuates between my set point (10 °C) from 5 °C to 30 °C. I insulated the TEC as much as I could.

Question: What should the parameters of PID (P,I,D) be?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried the auto-tuning as described in the manual under chapter 5?

Comment: The C100 (I have one) is on/off output. TEC's become very inefficient when driven on/off, you should drive them with a smooth filtered supply. A large temperature swing means too low a sample rate, increase it.